# prevent double form submit with javascript on h:commandLink in jsf under jdk 8

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf

We have a JSF/Tomcat/Hibernate/Oracle application that we would like to upgrade to Java 8. We develop using Eclipse. Upon upgrading to Java 8 (jdk 8) as well as upgrading to Eclipse Luna and Tomcat 7.0.54 we have experienced two issues. The less serious one is that some of the graphical renderings have a new look which is not as good as before. The more serious issue is that we have a double form submission prevention script that is now causing our h:commandLink components to hang up. After clicking on such a link, the URL gets appended with a #, and subsequent clicks on the link (or other buttons on the page) show our alert "Already submitted - please wait..." which comes from our script. Our script is:

```
// Prevent double form submissions
var defaultSubmit = null;
var formSubmitted = false;

function initForm() {
    if (defaultSubmit == null) {
        defaultSubmit = document.forms[0].submit;
        document.forms[0].submit = submitForm;
        document.forms[0].onsubmit = checkFormSubmission;
    }
    formSubmitted = false;
}
function checkFormSubmission() {
    if (formSubmitted) {
        alert('Already submitted - please wait...');
        return false;
    } else {
        formSubmitted = true;
        return true;
    }
}
function submitForm() {
    if (checkFormSubmission()) {
        if (defaultSubmit != null) {
            return defaultSubmit();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

</script>
```

The above script is part of a jsp file that gets included in many other jsp files within our application. It worked well using jdk 5, 6 and 7 but has problems now. h:commandButton's work OK, but the h:commandLink's cause the application to hang up as described above. How can this be fixed to work with jdk 8?

Answer (score 0):

An online search for the use of onsubmit with h:commandLink indicated that onclick would be a better choice, and this allowed a solution to our primary problem. First, we needed to replace "h:commandLink ..." by "h:commandLink onclick="return checkFormSubmission();" ... everywhere within the program. Also our script needed to be replaced by the new script:

```
var initialized = false;
var formSubmitted = false;

function initForm() {
    if (initialized == false) {
        document.forms[0].onsubmit = checkFormSubmission;
        initialized = true;
}
    formSubmitted = false;
}
function checkFormSubmission() {
    if (formSubmitted) {
        alert('Already submitted - please wait...');
        return false;
    } else {
        formSubmitted = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

When all of the above changes were made, our double click protection once again works as desired. Once a click is made on either an h:commandLink or an h:commandButton, a subsequent click pops up the alert telling the user: "Already submitted - please wait...", and this alert appears no matter which h:commandLink or h:commandButton is subsequently pressed. Which is our desired behavior.